# Using Prototype to load a JavaScript file from another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, prototypejs, same-origin-policy

Using Prototype, anyone know how to load a javascript file using Ajax.Request from another domain? Or if this is possible?

I believe this is possible with jquery, digg do it to load the Facebook API:

```
jQuery.ajax({type:"GET",
url:"http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php",
cache:true, dataType:"script"});
```

Source: http://cotnet.diggstatic.com/js/loader/370/digg_facebook

Without looking at the code, I'm guessing jquery has the smarts to use a proxy when url violates the same origin policy and dataType is script.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/introducing-a-cross-site-ajax-plugin-for-prototype) out.. It seems that there is a specific plugin which enables the functionality in Prototype library, the author mentions that e.g. jQuery supports it already for a long time, but it seems it's not supported by default it Prototype.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that was very helpful, I took a look at that which lead me to create and insert a script element to the api URL in the body in my answer.  You could also do it in the head but for the facebook api which I'm using they recommend putting it in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Thx to Thomas's answer, I created a FacebookApiLoader class to do this. Here's the source, only tested in Firefox 3 at the moment.  Hope this helps someone.  What this does is looks to see if there are any facebook api dependent elements on the page, and if there are then it will load the facebook api script by inserting it before the body closing tag.  This relies on the PrototypeJS library. Call facebookApiLoader.observe() in a page that might require the facebook api.

```
var FacebookApiLoader = Class.create({
  initialize: function() {
    this.observer = null
    this.observedElement = null
  },
  apiDependentsVisible: function() {
    if (null == this.observedElement) {
      // $('facebook-login') is a div in my site that
      // is display:none initially.  Once it is made
      // visible then the facebook api is needed.
      // Replace 'facebook-login' with id relevant for your site
      this.observedElement = $('facebook-login')
    }
    return this.observedElement.visible()
  },
  apiLoadCompleted: function() {
    try {
      return !Object.isUndefined(FB) && !Object.isUndefined(FB_RequireFeatures)
    } catch (e) {
    }
    return false
  },
  initAndRequireFeatures: function() {
    FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"],
      function() {
        FB.init('secret-put-your-app-value-here','/xd_receiver.html', {})
      }
    );
  },
  initFacebookConnect: function() {
    new PeriodicalExecuter(function(pe) {
      if (this.apiLoadCompleted()) {
        this.initAndRequireFeatures()
        pe.stop()
      }
    }.bind(this), 0.2);
  },
  loadApi: function() {
    // Use body for facebook script as recommended in Facebook
    // docs not to insert in head as some browsers have 
    // trouble with it
    body = $$('body')[0]
    // TODO use https protocol if page is secure
    script = new Element('script', { 'type': 'text/javascript',
      'src': 'http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php' })
    body.appendChild(script)
    this.initFacebookConnect()
  },
  loadApiIfRequired: function() {
    if (this.apiDependentsVisible()) {
      this.observer.stop()
      this.loadApi()
    }
  },
  observe: function() {
    if (null == this.observer) {
      this.observer = new PeriodicalExecuter(this.loadApiIfRequired.bind(this), 0.2)
    }
  }
});
// The FacebookApiLoader attributes are lazily loaded
// so creating a new facebookApiLoader
// is as low resource usage as possible
var facebookApiLoader = new FacebookApiLoader();
```

Then on any page that might need the Facebook api on demand, call

```
facebookApiLoader.observe();
```